# Haskell - finding k'th element from end, and haskell's can't match the pattern

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a recursive function that returns the k's element from the end.

This my attempt:

```
kElementFromEnd :: Int -> [x] -> x

kElementFromEnd _ [] = error "cannot request k item from empty list"
kElementFromEnd k [x]
    | k < 0 = error "k must be non negative"
    | k == 0 = last [x]
    | otherwise = kElementFromEnd (k-1) (init [x])
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

```
*Main> kElementFromEnd 2 [1,2,3]
*** Exception: EX2.hs:(4,1)-(8,54): Non-exhaustive patterns in function kElementFromEnd
```

I really don't understand why haskell can't match the pattern. What's going on that I'm not understanding?

Thanks

Comment: You could make this a whole lot simpler! `kElemFE n xs = reverse xs !! n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've only matched empty lists (`[]`) and single element lists (`[x]`).  I think you mean to replace `[x]`, a pattern which matches a single element list and assign's that single value to `x`, with simply `xs`, a pattern which matches any list not already matched.  This would look like

```
kElementFromEnd :: Int -> [x] -> x
-- This pattern matches the empty list
kElementFromEnd _ [] = error "cannot request k item from empty list"
-- This pattern is just a name, so it matches everything else
-- i.e. non-empty lists
kElementFromEnd k xs
    | k < 0 = error "k must be non negative"
    | k == 0 = last xs
    | otherwise = kElementFromEnd (k-1) (init xs)
```

And it would work as

```
> kElementFromEnd 0 [1..5]
5
> kElementFromEnd 4 [1..5]
1
> map (\i -> kElementFromEnd i [1..10]) [0..9]
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: but I want to take the last elements, where as the pattern of (x:xs) keeps splitting it to heads and tail. I want last and head. How do I signal haskell that I'm looking for a multiple element list?

Comment: Thanks! I must have misunderstood something though. say I were to write kElementFromEnd without first declaring it's signature (first line of code), how could haskell conclude that xs is a list? shouldn't I use the [x] notation to signal it's a list in the function's body?

Comment: @vondip `[x]` is a type, the `x` used here has nothing to do with what you name your function's arguments.  The type is completely equivalent to `Int -> [a] -> [a]` or `Int -> [element] -> [element]`.  When pattern matching on arguments, what you're actually doing is pattern matching on constructors of data types.  Lists have the constructors `[] :: [a]` and `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`.  Haskell also has special syntax sugar for working with list literals as `[a, b, c, d]`, but the compiler turns this into `a:(b:(c:(d:[])))` internally.  Thus, `[x] == x:[]`.

Comment: @vondip If you aren't matching on constructors, you're just using names by themselves, like `add x y = x + y` or `take5 xs = take 5 xs`.  The names used here of `x`, `y`, and `xs` just match whatever value is passed there, it's a named catch-all.  You can also use `_` syntax to match any value where you don't care to bind that value to a name, as in `const x _ = x`.  in this case Haskell can determine it's a list because you're calling `last :: [a] -> a` and `init :: [a] -> [a]` on it.  Haskell's smart enough to figure out that `xs` can only be a list.

Comment: @vondip "How could Haskell conclude that `xs` is a list?" Well, a couple ways: it's clearly a list in the first equation (since you use the pattern `[]`), and it's clearly a list in the second equation (since you pass it to `last` and `init`, which only work on lists).

Answer (score 4):

Writing such a function is definitely a good exercise. First, GHC can help you to catch errors like this. In particular `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` will issue a warning if your patterns are incomplete, preventing nasty run-time errors. With `-Werror` you can also make it an error, to be sure you won't miss the warning. It's not a bad practice to compile with `-Wall -Werror` to eliminate all possible warnings.

Second, to make the exercise harder: Since `init` is *O(n)*, your implementation of the function is *O(kn)* (or to be more precise *O(min(k,n) n)*. For very small *k* it doesn't matter that much, but if *k≈n*, you'll get quadratic performance. So I'd suggest you you to try to find an implementation that is

- *O(n)* (independent of *k*),
- works well for large, lazy lists; that is, traverse a list in such a way that if nothing else keeps the list in memory, the elements at the beginning of the list are continuously discarded by the GC; in particular, the space complexity should be independent of *n*.

Spoiler:

> `kElementFromEnd k xs = last $ zipWith const xs (drop k xs)`

Also, it's usually better to fail gracefully, as calling `error` means that your program exists immediately. So another improvement would be to make the type signature

```
kElementFromEnd :: Int -> [x] -> Maybe x
```